# Adding the values to the key on QGIS

Tags: qgis, labeling

I am trying to create a bird map. The symbols look like this on my map, the value is the label (s)

[image]

However, in my key they look like this

[image]

Is there a way for me to get the key to show the value as well and not just the symbology?

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. You should add more information, otherwise we don't know what you have and what you've tried. You have a point layer? The symbology is an SVG or a symbol created from attribute values? What do you mean by "key"? What you want should look like the `S` image or the `Skylark` image? There is a lot unclear in your question.

Answer (score 3):

You can add a Font Marker as a symbol layer and set a data driven override, e.g. `left ("name",1)`:

[image]

In the legend, double click the entries, activate `custom symbols` (see last screenshot), select again the font marker and manually introduce the corresponding character (data driven override here does not work for me):

[image]

Activate `custom symbols`, then click on the symbol to make the settings:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Set a label with the expression: `left(yourfieldname, 1)` and:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the "Text on Symbols" area in the "Legend" tab of the layer properties - especially the button "Set Labels from Expression" (see screenshot).
I think, this might be the solution for your problem.

[image: Screenshot]